# AzureAD - add permission error by showing raining cloud icon

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying AzureAD trial in order to use APIs provided by microsoft product (I am also registered in premium trial).

I've successfully registered my iOS app, but whenever I try to add permission, it shows raining cloud icon at "select permissions".

[image: raining cloud]

I tried browsers such as IE, safari, edge, and chrome but none worked.
Anyone who knows how to solve this issue, please help me out... Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone new to AzureAD, this can be avoided by:

1. Create quickApp
2. Get url to app (either native or not)
3. Put the url to in the field in permission.

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary problem with the Azure portal when trying to add delegated permissions to certain resources.  It has since been resolved.